# How can I plot 1-d list onto existing plot without knowing x locations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am plotting a graph with `datetime` and `power` which can be seen in the big blue line on the attached image.

After plotting the image, I am trying to insert the 1-d list (`only_unusual`) in the same plot.

Actually `df['power']` includes the values of the 1-d list (`only_unusual`).

But without including y axis alongside with `only_unusual` I can't plot the graph.

How can I plot the `only_unusual` list in the same plot so that it will be visible on the main blue line with a different color?

My code:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']), df['power'], color='b',label='Normal')
ax.scatter(only_unusual ,  color='red', label='Unusual',marker='o')
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.xlabel('Date Time')
plt.ylabel('power')
plt.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[image: My main plot]

My data:

```
only_unusual : [13.266, 4.213291, 2.756, 3.6722, 12.356, 12.193, 10.318, 12.203, 8.7549, 9.536, 9.10677, 1.417]




df :

        datetime              invno  power
0       2021-12-01 00:00:00    1     0.000
5       2021-12-01 01:00:00    1     0.000
10      2021-12-01 02:00:00    1     0.000
15      2021-12-01 03:00:00    1     0.000
20      2021-12-01 04:00:00    1     0.000
....     ...... ...... ....    ..     .....

1129    2021-12-10 09:00:00    5    2.914
1134    2021-12-10 10:00:00    5    10.318

...     ... ... ...
1149    2021-12-10 13:00:00    5     2.756
1154    2021-12-10 14:00:00    5     1.297
1159    2021-12-10 15:00:00    5     1.503
1164    2021-12-10 16:00:00   5      1.417
1169    2021-12-10 17:00:00    5     0.084
1170 rows × 3 columns
```

Comment: do you mean something like `ax.scatter(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']), only_unusual, color='red', label='Unusual', marker='o')`

Comment: Yes, when I used this line it gives my error like x, and y must be same size. Any idea to get rid of this error? I think I need to match datetime idx and only_unusual idx.

Comment: so it seems `only_unusual` is only a subset. i guess that's what this sentence meant: "`df['power']` includes the values of `only_unusual`"

Comment: Total length of df['datetime] is 1170, and usually only_unusual has len 6 or 7. What kind of informatin is required? I will try to provide here. After realizing different size, I came here for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If the list contains y values (`power`)

Normally we could find matching y values with [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), but since these are floats, we should use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to check with a tolerance.

1. Use [`np.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) with [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) to find `matches` with some tolerance:

   ```
   matches = df[np.isclose(df['power'].values[:, None], only_unusual).any(axis=1)]

   #                  datetime  invno   power
   # 1134  2021-12-10 10:00:00      5  10.318
   # 1149  2021-12-10 13:00:00      5   2.756
   # 1164  2021-12-10 16:00:00      5   1.417
   ```
2. Then scatter plot these `matches`:

   ```
   ax.scatter(pd.to_datetime(matches['datetime']), matches['power'], color='r', label='Unusual', marker='o')
   #                         ^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^
   ```

Full code (pandas 1.3.3, numpy 1.20.3, matplotlib 1.3.5):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'datetime': {0: '2021-12-01 00:00:00', 5: '2021-12-01 01:00:00', 10: '2021-12-01 02:00:00', 15: '2021-12-01 03:00:00', 20: '2021-12-01 04:00:00', 1129: '2021-12-10 09:00:00', 1134: '2021-12-10 10:00:00', 1149: '2021-12-10 13:00:00', 1154: '2021-12-10 14:00:00', 1159: '2021-12-10 15:00:00', 1164: '2021-12-10 16:00:00', 1169: '2021-12-10 17:00:00'}, 'invno': {0: 1, 5: 1, 10: 1, 15: 1, 20: 1, 1129: 5, 1134: 5, 1149: 5, 1154: 5, 1159: 5, 1164: 5, 1169: 5}, 'power': {0: 0.0, 5: 0.0, 10: 0.0, 15: 0.0, 20: 0.0, 1129: 2.914, 1134: 10.318, 1149: 2.756, 1154: 1.297, 1159: 1.503, 1164: 1.417, 1169: 0.084}})
only_unusual = [13.266, 4.213291, 2.756, 3.6722, 12.356, 12.193, 10.318, 12.203, 8.7549, 9.536, 9.10677, 1.417]

matches = df[np.isclose(df['power'].values[:, None], only_unusual).any(axis=1)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.plot(pd.to_datetime(df['datetime']), df['power'], color='b', label='Normal')
ax.scatter(pd.to_datetime(matches['datetime']), matches['power'], color='r', label='Unusual', marker='o')
ax.xaxis_date()
plt.xlabel('Date Time')
plt.ylabel('Power')
plt.legend()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

---

#### If the list contains x values (`datetime`)

1. We can just use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to find matching `datetime` rows:

   ```
   matches = df[df['datetime'].isin(only_unusual)]
   ```
2. Then use these `matches` (instead of `df`) for the scatter plot:

   ```
   ax.scatter(pd.to_datetime(matches['datetime']), matches['power'], color='r', label='Unusual', marker='o')
   #                         ^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^
   ```

Comment: Really thank you for your time and help. list contains y values. When I tried to match with y values, matches is extracting all datetime (not only required one). Wasn't it supposed to extract corresponding datetime?

Comment: are you able to edit your post with a sample of `df` and `only_unusual`?

Comment: Sure, let me add my data.

Comment: @giblegarcham using your sample data, i only get 3 rows in `matches`. i added the full code block i used. if you copy-paste that and it gives you different results, maybe it's a version issue (i tested with pandas 1.3.3, numpy 1.20.3, matplotlib 1.3.5)

Comment: Hi tdy. Thanks a lot. Gonna vote your answer. It helped me a lot. And if there is 0 in only_unusual then this will give me a problem because df['power'] has so many 0 cells.

Comment: great, glad it worked out

Comment: Yeah it worked. except for the 0 case. If there is 0 then I have to apply another logic before I get only_unusual to make matches.